# How is the event tied to the button in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2017 has an ASP.NET Core with Angular project template. I created it and it had a counter sample. The code was simple.

counter.component.html

```
<p>Current count: <strong>{{ currentCount }}</strong></p>

<button (click)="incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
```

counter.component.ts

```
export class CounterComponent {
    public currentCount = 0;

    public incrementCounter() {
        this.currentCount++;
    }
}
```

In the browser, it looked like,

```
<p>Current count: <strong>0</strong></p>

<button>Increment</button>
</counter>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</app></body></html></app>

<script src="/dist/vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I"></script>



    <script src="/dist/main-client.js?v=cH2S4H872p2E0HNFomc0vsA3ykslPAJyz8CIv7STiuY"></script>

</body>
```

I clicked the script with the cryptic name, but it was very long and difficult to read.

I think I could have created that kind of simple counter by hand using JavaScript, but then, I would have probably set the ID of the display element, called a function in the onClick event of the button, and then when it was clicked, I would have change the innerText of the element. But the generated code has none of that, and still worked. How does the number in  change when the Increment button is clicked?

And can I set a break point when the Increment button is clicked and follow the code step-by-step in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few basic Angular/Javascript concepts that you need to understand first.

1. Angular data binding - https://angular.io/guide/architecture

Yes, you could write Javascript to sync values in your component object with those in your template. But a primary reason for Angular is so that you don't have to do this. The goal is to separate the view from the object model and let Angular take care of this.

2. Bundling - https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-modules-bundling-transpiling/

The code in /dist/vendor.js is transpiled and bundled code. It was originally written in Typescript. It was transpiled into Javascript and then all the Javascript files were combined into one.

3. Debugging and Source maps - https://medium.com/@ttemplier/how-to-debug-the-typescript-source-code-of-angular2-99a593e2983f

Yes if you wanted to, you could put a breakpoint on the increment statement and step all the way through the Angular source. But first you would need to download the un-transpiled Typescript code for Angular and generate the source maps that map the original Typescript to the output Javascript.